# on clicking a button, opening a streamed page in new window or tab

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using .NET4 MVC3 VS2010. We are using ABCpdf to convert html to pdf and stream it to the browser.  The problem is that I need to figure out a way for the pdf be opened in a new window or tab.  I have read a bunch of posts on similar issue, but could find nothing to help with this specific case. 
Upon clicking a button (not a link) on a page, a controller action takes care of creating a memory stream from the html for that very page and then converts it to pdf and sends it to the browser.

Code in the view for that page:
            var pdfUrl = String.Format("window.location.href = '{0}';",          Html.BuildUrlFromExpressionForAreas(c => c.GeneratePdf(myUrl)));
            }
            @(Html.Button("btnPdf", "Generate PDF", HtmlButtonType.Button, pdfUrl)))

Code in MyController action:
        public ActionResult GeneratePdf(string url)
            Doc pdfDoc = new Doc();
            int docId;
            MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();

and a bunch of other code for pdf conversion..... then:
            byte[] pdfData = pdfDoc.GetData();
            outputStream.Write(pdfData, 0, pdfData.Length);
            outputStream.Position = 0;
            return new FileStreamResult(outputStream, "application/pdf");
        }

It works fine but the pdf is displayed in the same window/tab.  How can I stream the data to a new window or tab in the browser?
I am a newbee and would appreciate detailed help.
target property does not work for this case.  I could not work window.open into the view code for the button and I am not sure that would do the trick either.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use a normal link with `target="_blank"` attribute:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Generate PDF", 
    "GeneratePdf", 
    "MyController", 
    null,  
    new { 
        url = "some url",
        target = "_blank"
    }
)
```

or if you want a button you could use javascript:

```
<input type="button" value="Generate PDF" id="btnPdf" data-pdf-url="@Url.Action("GeneratePdf", "MyController", new { url = "some url" })" />
```

and then in a separate javascript file you could use jQuery and subscribe for the click event of this button and open a new window:

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnPdf').click(function() {
        // get the url of the data-pdf-url property of the button
        var url = $(this).data('pdf-url');
        window.open(url, 'pdf');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I worked out the code similar to your second suggestion, however using Firebug, I get "$ is not defined"

Comment: @FZF, that's jquery. Is it included in your page?

Comment: it is included in the master page.  I'll check into it more.

Comment: @FZF, yeah, normally the default ASP.NET MVC 3 project template includes jQuery in the `_Layout.cshtml`. Also sure that the `.js` file containing this script is included after jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

@Darin Dimitrov , Thanks, the page was missing the reference.  I fixed that problem, but it behaves strangely:  The first time I click the button it doesn't do anything (doesn't go back to any action in the controller.) the second time I click the button it opens a new tab but gives an error that he resource is unavailable and it shows it is looking for a view called undefined!  if I ignore this and go back to the original page and click the same button for the third time then it behaves as I hoped it would on the first click: it opens a new tab and displays the original page data streamed and formatted in pdf, all correctly!  any suggestions?  I really appreciate your help with this.  Here is my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#btnPdf").click(function () {
         var url = $(this).attr("href");
         $(this).attr("href", '@MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.BuildUrlFromExpressionForAreas<MyController>(c => c.GeneratePdf(Request.Url.ToString())))').bind("click",
                function () {
                    var win = window.open(url);
                    win.focus();
                    return false;
                });
     });
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov , I lost access to my original profile and I had to post my comment like an answer.  Sorry everyone, the answer above is not really an answer, but a follow up question on the comments below the first answer!

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, the code actually behaves quite bizarre when I go back to the original page and continue clicking: on first click nothing happens, second click I get a new window with error, third click it opens 1 new window with error and one with the correct pdf streamed to the browser, forth click opens one new win with error  and 2 new wins with pdf output,5th click gives one new error win and 3 new wins with pdf output,  so on and so forth.  Any suggestion what might be causing this strange behavior?